# Getting the list of dependencies of a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to read the dependencies of a target inside a Makefile?

I would like to do something like the following:

```
.INTERMEDIATE: temp1.txt
.INTERMEDIATE: temp2.txt
print-intermediates:
        @echo "Temp files: $(dependencies-of .INTERMEDIATE)"
```

The output of `make print-intermediate` would be

```
$ make print-intermediate
Temp files: temp1.txt temp2.txt
```

How can I access the list of dependencies of the `.INTERMEDIATE` target?

Comment: Given the way your recipe is written, what's wrong with `$?`, `$^` and `$^`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Recursive call of make.

There is no built-in function for this purpose. But there are some workarounds.
For example you can use recursive call of `make` with command line argument `-p`.

```
.INTERMEDIATE: temp1.txt
.INTERMEDIATE: temp2.txt 
deps = $(shell $(MAKE) -qp none | sed -n "/$(strip $(1)):/ p;" | \
  sed -e "s/$(strip $(1)): //g") 

print-intermediates:
        @echo "Temp files: " $(call deps,.INTERMEDIATE)

.PHONY: none
none:;
```

Comment: I removed the space before `.INTERMEDIATE` in the `$(call)` as make is sensitive to "random" spaces. In this case, and because of `$(strip)`, it didn't hurt anything but it is better to not have it there anyway.

Comment: Why the `none` target?

Comment: @gioele Because without `none` make tries to build default goal (`print-intermediates`), what causes infinite sequence of recursive invocations.

Comment: Wouldn't that be solved by adding `print-intermediate`, or the default goal, to `.PHONY`?

Comment: @gioele Not, because add target to `.PHONY` is a way to say, that this target is not a name of a file. Phony targets can be a default goal. You can remove `none`, if you can guarantee, that `print-intermediates` will never be a default goal. Another way to remove `none` is pass another target through the command line argument in recursive invocation. But it will harm readability (imho).

Comment: A single `sed` invocation invocation is sufficient: `$(shell $(MAKE) -qp | sed -n 's/^$(1): \(.*\)$$/\1/p')`.